# Delphi XE6 DLL: Unwanted export: TMethodImplementationIntercept

Tags: delphi, dll, rtti, delphi-xe6

When you compile a DLL in Delphi XE6, it automatically exports the function `TMethodImplementationIntercept` from `System.Rtti.pas`. I tried to find a way to avoid this export but didn't find any configuration or compiler directive that could do the trick.

The System.Rtti unit is nearly impossible to avoid because it's used indirectly by almost everything in delphi.

Is there a way to avoid exporting this function when building a DLL in XE6?

Comment: Just a question: Why is it important to avoid exporting this function?

Comment: First: It's useless in most cases. Second: It's weird.

Comment: @HEARTWARE one likes to be tidy

Comment: @Kekas Is this new in XE6?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I jumped from XE2 to XE6 so I don't know yet.

Answer (score 9):

The code in the `System.Rtti` unit looks like this:

```
{ This function has been added to be used from .s .c files in order to avoid use mangled names}
procedure TMethodImplementationIntercept(const obj:TMethodImplementation; AFrame: Pointer); cdecl;
begin
  obj.Intercept(AFrame);
end;
exports TMethodImplementationIntercept;
```

This function and the `exports` directive, were added in XE5.

> Is there a way to avoid exporting this function when building a DLL in XE6?

If your library includes the `System.Rtti` unit then the DLL will export that function. If you want to produce a DLL that does not export the function I can see the following options:

1. Use an older version of Delphi.
2. Don't include `System.Rtti` in your library.
3. Use a modified version of `System.Rtti` that does not export the function.
4. Modify the DLL after it has been produced to remove the function from the PE export table.

The first two options seem to me to be not very appealing. The third option seems attractive but I think it might turn out to be difficult to make work. It seems that this long standing trick no longer works. I've not yet been able to re-compile an RTL unit and avoid the dreaded *X was compiled with a different version of Y* error.

So that leaves the final option. Again, not massively attractive. You may well decide to just suck it up and accept this stray export. Perhaps a QC report might put a little pressure on Embarcadero to reconsider this decision.

For what it is worth, in my opinion no compiler library code should ever unconditionally export a function. It should be the consumer of the library rather than the implementer of the library that takes that decision.

Comment: I totally agree that `no compiler library code should ever unconditionally export a function`. Option 2 is not possible for me because as I said before, RTTI is used indirectly by almost everything. I have an automated build system that is already using the fourth option with a tool that I've developed. I'm considering to try the third option when I have the time because the fouth option seems more like a hack.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It is not possible to avoid `System.Rtti` since XE4 (I think) because it is used by `System.Classes`.

Comment: @Stefan Whilst it is possible to avoid `Classes` there's not much left when you do. The more I see of XE6, the more I prefer XE3.